# Wordpress Login Blank Page

Tags: wordpress

when I go into wordpress login, I have a blank page. I find tutorial to fix it in http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-wordpress-white-screen-of-death/.

when i trying to debug it, I have this error

> Notice: Constant WP_DEBUG already defined in /home/xxxxx/public_html/wp-config.php on line 72
>
> Notice: wp_enqueue_style was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in /home/xxxxxx/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3787

Can you help me to fix this error?

thank you

Comment: White screen with PHP: Read the error log of the server.

Answer (score 0):

You may be trying to enqueue your scripts outside of an action. You do not show any code on on how you are enqueuing your scripts so look for something like `wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src );` and make sure it is inside of a function

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts' );
function load_scripts() { 
    wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src );
}
```